# How can I store an SKScene including all SKSpriteNodes created within when app is closed?

Tags: ios, swift

This is my first question and am new to Swift so apologies for any slip in syntax or semantics ;)

I am building an iOS app using Swift and need to store the state of an own TablesScene class which is a subclass of SKScene when closing the app to get this back when re-opening it.
This scene is called by one of a number of ViewControllers that can be accessed through a Tab Bar Controller.

I am aware of NSCoder and have tried this out...

Added this property in AppDelegate to get a handle on the Scene...

```
var tablesScene: TablesScene?
```

... which I am populating in the TablesScene itself as per below...

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.tablesScene = self
    }
```

... then added this func to AppDelegate to get the proper directory for archiving ...

```
class func getPrivateDocsDir() -> String {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.LibraryDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent("Private Documents")
    var error:NSError?
    NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(documentsDirectory, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil, error: &error)
    return documentsDirectory

}
```

... then this to archive the Scene ...

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    self.saveContext()
    if let view = window?.rootViewController?.view {
        let documentsDirectory = AppDelegate.getPrivateDocsDir()
        let filePath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("autosaved-scene")
        let data = NSMutableData()
        let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWithMutableData: data)
        archiver.encodeObject(tablesScene, forKey: "AppDelegateSceneKey")
        archiver.finishEncoding()
        data.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true)
    }
}
```

... and this to retrieve back the TablesScene state...

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    if let view = window?.rootViewController?.view  {

        let dataPath = AppDelegate.getPrivateDocsDir().stringByAppendingPathComponent("autosaved-scene")
        if let codedData = NSData(contentsOfFile: dataPath) {
            let unarchiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver( forReadingWithData: codedData)
            let tablesScene = unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey("AppDelegateSceneKey") as? TablesScene
            unarchiver.finishDecoding()
        }

    }
}
```

... i am getting the following message but I feel there's something wrong with my approach.

```
[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is empty; did you forget to send -finishEncoding to the NSKeyedArchiver?
```